# Tell if a shared library was compiled with position independent code

Tags: macos, position-independent-code

Is there a way to tell whether an OSX shared library (`.dylib`) was compiled as position independent code/executable?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/58548/143186) you can run `otool -hv <file_path>` and look for a `PIE` flag.

Edit: I tested this and it does not work.

Edit 2: Actually it does work on executables. I'm not sure it works on shared libraries.

Comment: Did you get for shared libraries ? How to check PIC flag ?