# How to determine if an object is compiled with -fPIC?

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, binutils, fpic

I'd like to know whether an object or .a file is compiled with -fPIC enabled or not. Is there a way to know it (on both Linux and Mac OS X)? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the `file` command?

Comment: It doesn't show the info. Is there an option to specify. $ gcc -fPIC -c  print.c 
$ file print.o 
print.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64
$ gcc -c  print.c 
$ file print.o 
print.o: Mach-O 64-bit object x86_64

Comment: It was just a guess....

Comment: That one is based on readelf and binutils is not supported well on Mac OS X. So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622448/tell-if-a-shared-library-was-compiled-with-position-independent-code tells how to do it on OS X with `otools`. Google is your friend.

Comment: Again. Please test on your own. It doesn't work. I need .a or .o file. It shows executable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell, with something like objdump, if an object file has been built with -fPIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1340402/608639) and [Tell if a shared library was compiled with position independent code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48622448/608639).

Comment: Again, these are not for Mac.